# Use Custom dialog to accquire datetime objects in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, dialog, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to add an custom dialog to acquire datetime objects from the user.

I created a main Gui (MainWindowStart3.py) and a dialog window (DateAndtimePicker.py) via qtdesigner, converted them to py and imported those in the main python file with:

```
from MainWindowStart3 import Ui_MainWindow
from DateAndTimePicker import Ui_Dialog
```

I create two classe:
 - for the dialog:

```
class DialogInterface (QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        # self.ui = Ui_Dialog
        # self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setUi(self)
```

- for the MainWindow:

```
class UserInterface (Ui_MainWindow):
    def addFunctions(self, MainWindow):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.StartCharging)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.stop_charging)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.handleDialogWindow)
        ...
```

handleDialogWindow is the function to create the dialog window:

```
def handleDialogWindow(self):
        dialog = DialogInterface(self)
        result = dialog.exec_()
```

However, when I click in the GUI on that button, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "RasPiInterfacer.py", line 134, in handleDialogWindow
>       dialog = DialogInterface(self)   File RasPiInterfacer.py", line 24, in **init**
>       QtWidgets.QDialog.**init**(self,parent) TypeError: QDialog(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] =
>   Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'UserInterface'

line 134 corresponds to `dialog = DialogInterface(self)`

line 24 to `QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)`

I am new to GUI and dialogs and do not see where the error. My approach is inspired by the answers of this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760622/pyqt4-create-a-custom-dialog-that-returns-parameters#5760796) question.

Thank you very much for your time and patience with me in advance :-)

17-09-04: Is there any information I should add for you guys to ease finding the solution for my problem?

17-09-07: 
I did some changes to the code and now the dialog appears. Sadly I do not understand why this works now.

I changed the import statement of the dialog:

```
from DateAndTimePicker import Ui_Dialog as Form
```

And I made changes to the function called with

```
self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.handleDialogWindow)
```

it now reads:

```
    def handleDialogWindow(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
    dialog.show()
```

And now it works. How and Why?
Thanks