# Not able to pass the file name from input windows to mainwindow class in PyQt5,

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a 2 classes 
1. Main_window another is Load_file_window.
When I Press a Load_file option in my Mainwindow, it should open Load_file_window and browse the file and send the file name to my main windows both are 2 different classes.  I'm able to browse the file from Load_file_window but when I tried to pass that value to Mainwindow its not happening.
How can I proceed with this?

This code will run in windows machine, with Python PyQt5 Module

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QInputDialog,QFileDialog,QMessageBox,QWidget)

class Ui_Load_FILE(QWidget):
    def _init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent=parent
        self.Loaded_File_data=[]
    def setupUi(self, Load_FILE):
        Load_FILE.setObjectName("Load_FILE")
        Load_FILE.resize(581, 89)
        self.Load_group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Load_FILE)
        self.Load_group_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 561, 81))
        self.Load_group_box.setTitle("")
        self.Load_group_box.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.Load_progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.Load_group_box)
        self.Load_progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 471, 16))
        self.Load_progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.Load_progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.Import_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Load_group_box)
        self.Import_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 10, 75, 23))
        self.Import_button.setObjectName("Import_button")
        self.File_Name= self.Import_button.clicked.connect (self.openFileNameDialog)
        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect()
        self.Input_textBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Load_group_box)
        self.Input_textBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 411, 31))
        self.Input_textBox.setObjectName("Input_textBox")        
        self.Input_txtbx_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Load_group_box)
        self.Input_txtbx_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 47, 13))
        self.Input_txtbx_lbl.setObjectName("Input_txtbx_lbl")
        self.Load_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Load_group_box)
        self.Load_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 50, 75, 23))
        self.Load_button.setObjectName("Load_button")
        self.File1=self.Load_button.clicked.connect(self.Load_Action)
        self.retranslateUi(Load_FILE)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Load_FILE)
        return self.File1
    def retranslateUi(self, Load_FILE):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Load_FILE.setWindowTitle(_translate("Load_FILE", "Load File"))
        self.Import_button.setText(_translate("Load_FILE", "Import"))
        self.Input_txtbx_lbl.setText(_translate("Load_FILE", "Load_File"))
        self.Load_button.setText(_translate("Load_FILE", "Load"))

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        '''Opens Files diralog to browse the data'''
        fileName=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(caption='Open file',directory='.',filter="FILE Files (*.std *.FILE);;All Files (*.*)")
        if fileName[0]!='':
            self.Input_textBox.setText(fileName[0])
        else:            
            msg='Please select a File'
            self.Messagebox(msg,'info','Please select a File')
        return fileName
    def Load_Action(self,Load_FILE):        
        self.File_Name=self.Input_textBox.text()        
        if self.File_Name:
            print(self.File_Name)
            return self.File_Name
        else:
            self.Messagebox('Please browse a file then try to load the file','info','Please select a file before you load')

    def Messagebox(self,msg_text,msgtype='info',title='Message Box'):
        ''' Message is a function to call the message box in PyQt Quickly.  msgtype can be (info, warn,que,criti).
            msg_text is the msg you want to display, Title will be window Title'''
        if msgtype=='info':
            reply=QMessageBox.information(self,title,msg_text,QMessageBox.Ok ,QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif msgtype=='warn':
            reply=QMessageBox.warning(self,title,msg_text,QMessageBox.Ok ,QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif msgtype=='que':
            reply=QMessageBox.question(self,title,msg_text,QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No ,QMessageBox.Yes)
        elif msgtype=='criti':
            reply=QMessageBox.critical(self,title,msg_text,QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel ,QMessageBox.Ok)
        return reply

## THIS IS MY LOAD_FILE_WINDOW CODE

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Tool_Main_Frame.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QInputDialog,QFileDialog,QMessageBox,QWidget,QMainWindow,QDialog)
from Load_FILE import Ui_Load_FILE

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1390, 914)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1390, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.File = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.File.setObjectName("File")
        self.Menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.Menu.setObjectName("Menu")
        self.View = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.View.setObjectName("View")
        self.Data = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.Data.setObjectName("Data")
        #self.Data.setShortcut('Alt+D')
        self.Export = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.Data)
        self.Export.setObjectName("Export")
        self.Import = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.Data)
        self.Import.setObjectName("Import")
        #self.Import.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        self.Help = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.Help.setObjectName("Help")
        self.Editmenu=QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.Editmenu.setObjectName("Edit")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.Load = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Load.setObjectName("Load")
        self.Save = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Save.setObjectName("Save")
        self.Save.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        self.Save_As = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Save_As.setObjectName("Save_As")
        self.Save_As.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+S")
        self.Exit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Exit.setObjectName("Exit")
        self.Exit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.Exit.triggered.connect(self.Exit_the_main_window)
        self.Open = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Open.setObjectName("Open")
        self.Open.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.Load_CSV = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Load_CSV.setObjectName("Load_CSV")
        self.Export_Excel = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Export_Excel.setObjectName("Export_Excel")
        self.Export_CSV = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Export_CSV.setObjectName("Export_CSV")
        self.Export_TXT = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Export_TXT.setObjectName("Export_TXT")
        self.Load_FILE = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Load_FILE.setObjectName("Load_FILE")

        k=self.Load_FILE.triggered.connect(self.Open_Load_Action)
        self.Load_FILE.setShortcut('Ctrl+L')
        self.Load_Excel = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Load_Excel.setObjectName("Load_Excel")
        self.Load_Txt = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.Load_Txt.setObjectName("Load_Txt")
        self.File.addAction(self.Open)
        self.File.addAction(self.Save)
        self.File.addAction(self.Save_As)
        self.File.addAction(self.Exit)
        self.Export.addAction(self.Export_Excel)
        self.Export.addAction(self.Export_CSV)
        self.Export.addAction(self.Export_TXT)
        self.Import.addAction(self.Load_FILE)
        self.Import.addAction(self.Load_Excel)
        self.Import.addAction(self.Load_Txt)
        self.Data.addAction(self.Import.menuAction())
        self.Data.addAction(self.Export.menuAction())
        self.Help.addSeparator()
        self.menubar.addAction(self.File.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.Menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.Editmenu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.View.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.Data.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.Help.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "TOOL_TOOL"))
        self.File.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.Menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
        self.View.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.Data.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Data"))
        self.Export.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Export"))
        self.Import.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Import"))
        self.Help.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.Editmenu.setTitle(_translate('MainWindow','Edit'))
        self.Save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.Save_As.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save As.."))
        self.Exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.Open.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))        
        self.Load_CSV.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load_CSV"))
        self.Export_Excel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export_Excel"))
        self.Export_CSV.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export_CSV"))
        self.Export_TXT.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export_TXT"))
        self.Load_FILE.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load_FILE"))
        self.Load_Excel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load_Excel"))
        self.Load_Txt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load_Txt"))

    def Open_Load_Action(self):

        self.Load_FILE = QDialog()
        self.Load_FILE_ui = Ui_Load_FILE()
        self.Load_FILE_ui.setupUi(self.Load_FILE)
        self.Load_FILE.show()
        self.Load_FILE.exec_()  #<<----- After this all my code is not working as I wanted 

    def Exit_the_main_window(self):
        sys.exit(Main_Application.exec_())


def Launch_app():

    import sys
    Main_Application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    First_time_loading=True
    ui_Main_Window = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui_Main_Window.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    if First_time_loading==True:
        First_time_loading=False
        sys.exit(Main_Application.exec_())

Launch_app()
```

## This is my Main File

I'm expecting the file selected in load file to come into my main windows but its not happening and the windows also not getting closed.

Comment: Please, create a minimal example, instead of posting your whole file. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760622/pyqt4-create-a-custom-dialog-that-returns-parameters